# TypeError: hosts.fileExists is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I am trying to build my package and I get this error: TypeError: host.fileExists is not a function
I am not sure why this happened all of a sudden.

I tried to install `tsify` according to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4565 , but it did not help

here is the error:
[image]
here is my package.json dependencies:

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.1.3",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.2.1",
    "@babel/core": "~7.12.17",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "~7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "~7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-react": "~7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "~7.12.17",
    "@babel/register": "~7.12.13",
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.12.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.34",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "4.2.4",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.628.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.9.0",
    "cross-fetch": "3.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cypress": "^7.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "emotion": "^10.0.27",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "eslint": "7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "husky": "^2.4.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.9",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-icu": "^2.0.0",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "intl-messageformat": "^9.4.7",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "junit-report-merger": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.8",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.13.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "mochawesome": "^3.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^1.0.7",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5",
    "nightwatch": "^1.5.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.107.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "otpauth": "^7.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.1.0",
    "postcss-custom-media": "8.0.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.6.0",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.7",
    "react-intl": "^5.12.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-transition-group": "4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tachyons": "^7.0.1-5",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  }
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Your version of `prettier-plugin-organize-imports` is too old for your version of typescript.

Either remove `prettier-plugin-organize-imports` or upgrade it. Current version is 3.2.1.